# Time scale turbulence flow -distance between two particles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, turbulence

I want to estimate the time interval, $\tau$, during which the original distance $L$ between two fluid particles become much larger. I assume that the motion takes place in the inertial interval.

I don't know how to approach this problem yet but I think that I must use dimensional analysis.

My first thought was to calculate the Kolmogorov scales $L_N$ and $v_N$ and than say that $\tau=v_N \cdot L_N$. But since $v_N$ should be the velocity difference two points appart $r\sim L_N$ I don't think it's the right way to go.

Can someone help me how I should start solving the problem or how I should think?

Comment: The problem is not simple. Batchelor has already  solved this problem, in the context of turbulent diffusion in atmosphere. Search for "Turbulent diffusion Batchelor". Of course the final solution is in terms of certain statistics of turbulence which must be found by experimentation.

Comment: There is also a simpler Richardson law. Overall, have a look at the chapter 2 of "Turbulence and diffusion" by Oleg Bakunin.